# Is there a way to put multiple values in map with the same key?

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I was wondering, is there a way to put multiple values for the same key in a map? In my assignment, I am to put the following to a map:

Key (AnimalType)  Values (AnimalType within AnimalType)

Mammal : whale bat deer lion|tiger|cheetah

Bird: ostrich parrot

Fish: goldfish greatWhite|tigerShark

Reptile: alligator turtle|tortoise

Strings with a '|' on it means "or", therefore in the mammal group, it can only be whale, bat, deer, and any of the last three, not all three (lion or tiger or cheetah). Is there a way to make it so that Mammal, Bird, Fish, and Reptile are keys while the Strings on the right side of the ':' are values? Only in this case, not all of them should be values since I have to choose between lion, tiger and cheetah or any of the strings with '|' on them. Please comment down below if my question made no sense and I will clarify as its kind of hard to put in words for me. I will appreciate any help you can give. Thank you!

Comment: Use a `List` and map that to your key(s)

Comment: It is not clear how it is going to be used, and what are the semantic around "and" or "or". What is the difference between "bat" and "lion" (except that the latter doesn't fly, usually) for example? It seems that you need a combination of mapping and then a type hierarchy like `mammel -> whale, bat, deer, felidae` and `felidae` can be `lion | tiger | cheetah`.

Comment: The simplest way. If you can import libraries, is to use guava multimap. The [ArrayListMultiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) might be the class of choice.

Answer (score 0):

is your map only allowing 1 of the "|" values but should simultaneously allow all of the " " values?

```
whale bat deer lion <- valid
whale bat deer tiger <- valid
whale bat lion tiger <- invalid
```

That being said map will **override** the existing value if given the key provided is the same

But if you are using animals as keys and animalTypes as values you might be able to sort out the mutually-exclusive constraints by passing through your keys though another map

**Edit 2**

*potential spoilers redacted to better follow community guideline*

Comment: I'm not certain if I'm correct but I'm guessing your exercise is to have animals in the same group (i.e. "lion" and "tiger") mapped to the same category. So that when it gets inserted in another Map or Set they get filtered out. Again I don't know if you need to retrieve these values later or just store the animals in categories would be sufficient

Comment: Please give the OP time to at least show their attempt first. Otherwise you're cheating them the opportunity to learn to create their own code and not motivating them to improve their question up to site standards. Please look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to review those standards.